# Android drag and drop on another view

Tags: android

I'm making Android application and I want this feature:
User can drag some view and when he dropt on some another view, I can register that he dropt on some view and do some work with that view.

**For example:**

There are two ImageView, one blue one red, and there is thrid ImageView, when user dropt third ImageView on blue one I have to call `method1()` and otherwise when user dropt on red one I have to call `method2()`.

I have implemented standrad drag listener:

```
imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    Log.e(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.e(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                    Log.e(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                    Log.e(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                    Log.e(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.e(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");

                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Measure the `ImageViews` with `Rects` and check if they `intercept` in case of `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the current problem? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Amy, how can I get rect from ImageView. Is it any nicer way to do?
Shark I have explain what I have tried to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate rects. You should call `setOnDragListener` two times, once on the red image view to handle the drop events on it, and once on the blue image view to handle drop events on it. Also just in case, I don't see the code where you need to call `startDrag` on the view that user is dragging during the touch event to start the drag.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to call `view.startDrag` in order to listen to the callbacks.

You can move your view in `ACTION_MOVE`, and check the intersection in `ACTION_DROP`.

This can also be directly achieved by `OnTouchListener`.

You can get the full example [here](https://hemsha.medium.com/drag-listener-android-a9c47cd266dd).